# Django Admin: ManytoMany Model filter, the other way

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I'm stuck on using django's admin feature.

How do I use admin's list_filter for the pizza from toppingsAdmin?

```
For example, I have these models,
class Topping(models.Model):
    # ...

class Pizza(models.Model):
    # ...
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping)


From PizzaAdmin, I can call list_filter = ('toppings',)
```

But, How do I call pizzas from toppingsAdmin. Seems like `list_filter = ('pizzas',)` does not work, because it doesn't have it as variable inside the Topping model.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add [related_name](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.related_name) to your toppings field in Pizza model:

```
toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping, related_name='pizzas')
```

Now you can use the 'pizzas' in the list_filter

Comment: Hm, that gives me ImproperlyConfigured error. refers to field 'pizzas' that is missing from the model.